# Rails : simple_form : Getting an empty string from checkbox collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following code in my views

`<%= f.input :role_names, as: :check_boxes, collection: @program.role_names %>`

And whenever I submit the form I am getting values something like `["admin, "moderator", ""]` but I was expecting something like `["admin, "moderator"]` , why is this?

Moreover I made a inspect element, and there was a `<input name="user[role_names][]" type="hidden" value="">` tag after the last check box, within the same control-group. I suppose this is getting added at the last in the `params[:user][:recipient_role_names]`.

How should I handle this? I know I can do a `reject(&:blank?)` but is there a cleaner way on `params[:user][:recipient_role_names]`?
I also want to know why the input element is getting added? Is it a bug in simple form or I have done something wrong?

Other info:

1. simple_form gem version: 2.0.4
2. rails version: 3.2.8

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a Rails' feature. You'll be able disable it in Rails 4. You can read more about this on [simple form issue #603](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/603) and [Rails issue #5402](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5402)

Comment: perfect.. ll accept in 5 mins.. some time constraint.. cant accept now.. Btw I would love to understand why.. do you have any idea why this is a rails feature? I mean why they made this feature? and is this supposed to fix somethings else, if so what was that? It would be great if you could explain about it a little.. thx in advance..

Comment: you can read explanation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box (it's Gotcha section)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `include_hidden: false` to your input params:

```rb
<%= f.input :role_names, 
  as: :check_boxes, 
  collection: @program.role_names, 
  include_hidden: false 
%>
```

And the empty string value won't be sent in the array.

---

Obs: I've just added the simple_form input code here for quick reference, as it was Vasily's answer that pointed me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: removing the hidden input makes checkboxes uncheckable, which is not desired